# VBA : Bulk setting a variable of a range object from an array, other then just .value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, optimization

Setting properties of a range object, cell by cell is super slow. Except for when just splat the entire contents of an array into the .value

For example.
Range("A1:Z1000000").value = Arr

If want to create a pattern of colours for example, have to set it cell by cell. Which can take a long time. Rather then just setting colours into an array and setting whole property at once.

Just as a simple test, if it was possible, I'd expect this to work but unfortunately it doesn't.

```
Sub test()

Dim Arr1() As Variant, Arr2() As Variant
Dim y As Long, x As Long
Dim Redfnt As Variant, blkfnt As Variant

Redfnt = RGB(0, 0, 0)
blkfnt = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Arr1 = Selection.Value
ReDim Arr2(1 To UBound(Arr1, 1), 1 To UBound(Arr1, 2))

For y = 1 To UBound(Arr1, 2)
    For x = 1 To UBound(Arr1, 1)

        Arr1(x, y) = Arr1(x, y) * 2

        If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Arr2(x, y) = Redfnt
        Else
            Arr2(x, y) = blkfnt
        End If

    Next x
Next y

Selection.Value = Arr1
Selection.Font.Color = Arr2


End Sub
```

Does anyone know if its possible?

Comment: No it's not possible to do this.  Best you can do is make two separate ranges (one for each color) and apply color directly to each range when you're done building them.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Autofilter()`:

```
Sub test()

    Dim Arr1() As Variant

    Dim Redfnt As Variant, blkfnt As Variant
    Redfnt = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    blkfnt = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    With Selection ' reference selection object
        Arr1 = .Value ' store selection values
        With Intersect(.EntireRow, .Parent.UsedRange) ' reference the range with the same rows as 'Selection' and spanning all used range columns
            With .Resize(, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) ' reference a one column "helper" range right outside the used range in the same 'Selection' rows 
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=MOD(ROW(),2)" ' write referenced helper range with a formula giving the row evenness
                .Offset(-1).Resize(1).Value = "header" ' write a dummy header right on the top of referenced "helper" range
                With .Offset(-1).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1) ' expand the "helper" range to encompass the dummy header and reference it
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="0" ' filter on even rows
                    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font.Color = Redfnt ' give filtered range its proper font color
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="1" ' filter on uneven rows
                    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font.Color = blkfnt 'give filtered range its proper font color
                    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove filters
                    .ClearContents ' clear "helper" range
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With

    Dim y As Long, x As Long
    For y = 1 To UBound(Arr1, 2)
        For x = 1 To UBound(Arr1, 1)
            Arr1(x, y) = Arr1(x, y) * 2
        Next x
    Next y
    Selection.Value = Arr1

End Sub
```